# save contacts using safari

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, safari, mobile-safari

I want to add the contact info like email , cell , fax , address into the contacts of iphone, this is fairly simple using app but i want  to  place a button or link on my website which will be opened on safari, and by clicking that button/link, the whole contact information will be saved into iphone contacts. or at least the information wil be autofilled in save contact form

please guide me if any one has an clue. this will be done ideally by placing some meta or specif formatted href tags in my page but i dont know the exact solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first thought was a vCard, but perhaps [they don't work](http://thecodetrain.co.uk/2009/11/adding-a-vcard-to-your-iphone-address-book-from-a-web-page/)... at least they didn't a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Place a button with the href directed to a .vcf file. For example, going to this link: https://vcard.link/card/DUo2.vcf on an iPhone will prompt the contact to come up in iPhone format and will prompt you to save the contact.